# 'ViewController' does not conform to protocol

Tags: ios, swift, tableview, viewcontroller

I was learning from techotopia.com tutorial. I have copied all code from there, and I have an problem "Type 'ViewController' does not conform to protocol 'UITableViewDataSource'".

[Code and errors are on this screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aaWSp.png)

There was a problem like this on stackoverflow, but in that case the problem was a typo, so I dare to ask.

Comment: I am talking about this tutorial: http://www.techotopia.com/index.php/An_Swift_iOS_8_Twitter_Integration_Tutorial_using_SLRequest

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not finished implementing the required methods for the TableViewDataSource protocol. You should probably go on with the tutorial until you implemented the cellForRow method